# fuzzy LEFT join with R

Tags: r, join, dplyr, fuzzyjoin

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 <- tibble(col1 = c("apple", "banana", "carrot"),
              col2 = as.numeric(0:2),
              col3 = as.numeric(0:2))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   col1   col2  col3
#>   <chr> <int> <int>
#> 1 apple     0     0
#> 2 banana    1     1
#> 3 carrot    2     2

df2 <- tibble(col4 = c("app", "carr"), col5 = c(5, 9), matched = rep(TRUE, 2))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   col4   col5 matched
#>   <chr> <dbl> <lgl>  
#> 1 app       5 TRUE   
#> 2 carr      9 TRUE
```

I've got two data frames above `df1` and `df2`. **I need to create a new column for `df1` that tells whether each row matches with an entry in `df2`, or not.**

I also have to fuzzy match, and the fuzziness need to be case insensitive (hence the custom `ci_str_detect` function):

```
ci_str_detect <- function(x, y){str_detect(x, regex(y, ignore_case = TRUE))}

df1 %>% 
  fuzzy_inner_join(df2, by = c("col1" = "col4"), match_fun = ci_str_detect)
#># A tibble: 2 x 6
#>  col1    col2  col3 col4   col5 matched
#>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <lgl>  
#>1 apple      0     0 app       5 TRUE   
#>2 carrot     2     2 carr      9 TRUE
```

Unfortunately (in this case) the fuzzyjoin R package appears to only do INNER JOINs, and not the LEFT JOIN that I need.

Ultimately I need this output:

```
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   col1    col2  col3 col4   col5  matched
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <lgl>  
#> 1 apple      0     0 app       5  TRUE   
#> 2 banana     1     1 NA       NA  FALSE 
#> 3 carrot     2     2 carr      9  TRUE
```

... and a LEFT JOIN would provide the intermediate data frame shown below, that I could replace `NA` with `FALSE` to get what I ultimately want (directly above).

```
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   col1    col2  col3 col4   col5  matched
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <lgl>  
#> 1 apple      0     0 app       5  TRUE   
#> 2 banana     1     1 NA       NA  NA 
#> 3 carrot     2     2 carr      9  TRUE
```

How can I fuzzy LEFT join in R?

Comment: Are you sure you would expect the values for banana to be `col2 == 2` and `col3 == 2`. When I try `fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, match_fun = ci_str_detect, by = c(col1 = "col4"))`, I get  `structure(list(col1 = c("apple", "banana", "carrot"), col2 = c(0, 
1, 2), col3 = c(0, 1, 2), col4 = c("app", NA, "carr"), col5 = c(5, 
NA, 9), matched = c(TRUE, NA, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))`

Comment: @biomiha that's the answer, I didn't know there was a `fuzzy_left_join` function. Wow. You can put that as the answer and I'll mark solved. And yes, I did also copy/paste/logic wrong above and have corrected that. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Voila :)

```
fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, match_fun = ci_str_detect, by = c(col1 = "col4"))
```

Comment: tangent - do you know why either `"col1"` or `col1` will work above? Same reason `library(dplyr)` or `library("dplyr")` will work?

Comment: I have to say, I'm never entirely clear on the rules of NSE but yes, I think that's the best explanation, i.e. that it can evaluate both unquoted and quoted strings.

Comment: But I try `df1 %>% fuzzy_inner_join(df2, by = c("col1" = "col4"), match_fun = ci_str_detect)`, R also get right tibble. Maybe later version fix this issue.

Comment: It has nothing to do with NSE, just that names of a vector can be quoted or unquoted, so `c(name = "value")` is equal to `c("name" = "value")`